# Efficiently take N lowest bits of GMP mpz_t

Tags: c++, c, performance, bit-manipulation, gmp

There is `mpz_class` C++ wrapper of [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) type `mpz_t`. Having `mpz_class` number what is the most efficient way to take its `N` lowest bits to create another `mpz_class` number?

Of course I can do following masking operation

```
size_t N = 273; // how many lo bits to take
mpz_class x = ... ; // fill with something...
mpz_class mask = (mpz_class(1) << N) - 1; // mask having N 1-bits
mpz_class result = x & mask; // final result, N lowest bits taken
```

But this masking needs lots of unnecessary bit-and operations and slows down code. Maybe there is some shortcut for that like `result = x.take_lo(N);`?

Also it is possible that `mpz_class` is lacking such shortcut, but at least maybe C API has this function? Because any `mpz_class` can be easily converted without overhead to C type `mpz_t` through `mpz_t c_num = x.get_mpz_t();`. So it is fine for me to have `.take_lo(N)` shortcut within C API only.

Comment: "and slows down code" It would be nice if you edited your answer to show us the profiler showing that it actually does and is a bottleneck in your code.

Comment: The [C API](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division) has `mpz_tdiv_r_2exp`: divide by a power of 2 and take the remainder.  That's what you want, and it  [uses the obvious efficient implementation](https://github.com/sethtroisi/libgmp/blob/master/mpz/tdiv_r_2exp.c).  Seems worth a try.

Comment: @Kaihaku My code is intense with this masking operations. But anyway when you do coding it is very nice to know all Best available functions/operations and use them. Here definitely doing AND operations is not necessary, you just have to copy lowest N bits to new number and that's it, no need for AND.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! Exactly what's needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there's no C++ operator overload or function for `mpz_class`, you can indeed use: [**`mpz_tdiv_r_2exp`**](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division) provided by the C API. e.g.,

```
mpz_tdiv_r_2exp(result.get_mpz_t(), x.get_mpz_t(), N);
```

note: `cdiv` and `fdiv` variants are available too.

Using `mp_bitcnt_t` as the type for `(N)`, or `static_cast<mp_bitcnt_t>(N)` as the argument, would be more robust - as `mp_bitcnt_t` seems to be unconditionally defined as `unsigned long`, which *may* not match `size_t`.

Comment: Are you sure that your suggested function is faster than my solution and optimized? Because I opened your linked documentation and under function see a comment `For the 2exp variants the divisor is 2^b. These functions are implemented as right shifts and bit masks.` So as I understand it does bit masking hence does same as I do lots of unneeded AND operations.

Comment: Alright, I wrote code to do time measure and your function appeared `2.1x` times faster than my AND-masking solution. So if your function still does AND operation then at least it does this twice faster. So accepting and upvoting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: As @NateEldredge posted [code link](https://github.com/sethtroisi/libgmp/blob/master/mpz/tdiv_r_2exp.c) in comment, one can see by this link that `mpz_tdiv_r_2exp` indeed doesn't do AND-ing and just copies lower data of a number. So it is quite optimal.