# How to split an instance of GMP's mpz_t into two instances, memory-efficiently?

Tags: c++, gmp

**tl;dr**:
Is there a way to split the data of one `mpz_t` into two `mpz_t` instances and leave the data in its place in memory, thus having a constant time operation, no matter how much data is getting split in two parts?

I need to split it only at the boundaries of the limbs (elements of the `mpz_t`), i.e. no sub-element bit shifting is required.

**Details**:
I want to optimize an algorithm that's already working. The algorithm is intended to process numbers in the range of a few GB for a single number.

My question is similar to [Efficiently take N lowest bits of GMP mpz_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228373/efficiently-take-n-lowest-bits-of-gmp-mpz-t) . The difference is that I also need to avoid the copying of large amounts of data. I don't want to copy data from an existing number. Instead, I am looking for a way to keep the number's data in place, but have two instances of `mpz_t` point at different regions of the same data.

**Why I want this:**
One of my previous performance optimizations is to process the number iteratively, starting from the least significant end of the number. That yields a good performance boost. However, for chopping off data from that end, my current implementation copies data from the original number (See other linked question) and then the original number is shifted. This has the disadvantages that it takes more time and, most notably, more memory during the operation. That's significant if a single number has a few GB.

**What I currently do**:

```cpp
mpz_class n = ...; // huge number
mpz_class chunk; // will hold the part of n that we chopped off

size_t limbs_to_chop_off = 12345;
size_t bits_to_chop_off = sizeof(mp_limb_t) * 8 * limbs_to_chop_off;

mpz_tdiv_r_2exp(chunk.get_mpz_t(), n.get_mpz_t(), bits_to_chop_off);
n >>= bits_to_chop_off;
    
// process chunk ...
```

Comment: Could you work at the MPN level, i.e. avoid using mpz_* functions, use only mpn_* functions, on those pieces?

Comment: mpz_roinit_n / MPZ_ROINIT_N could be relevant. https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Special-Functions

Comment: @MarcGlisse the mpz_roinit_n is a good start. If I don't find an even better solution, this will already improve my code. Thanks!

Comment: I might also be able to pre-chunk all parts and thereby start chopping at the MSB side instead of the LSB side (In reverse to my later processing order).This way I can chop off small parts and only remove the MSB parts of n, which might allow the GMP implementation to free memory iteratively. The copying of the small chunks will still be there, but not the shifting of n, which is the biggest part.